# Transisting to different link when clicking on imageview android

Tags: android

I have used an `ImageView` and added a link to it. I have set listeners to it. Here is the code:

```
case R.id.imgLogo:
    String url = "http://www.xyz.com";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
```

But upon clicking on the imageview what ever is the "www.xyz.com" value it is taking to some different webpage.

Can I know what is the mistake?

Comment: "some different webpage" what is that page url?

Comment: @Arun the loading webpage is http://ww2.dinamikaprinting.com/?folio=7POYGN0G2

Comment: clear your browser cache and check!

Comment: your code is correct. i think you are doning same thing in multiple imageview click. thats why it happend..???

Comment: check this link and check your manifest file too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515927/android-displaying-web-page-using-intent

Comment: @user2143817 shall we know real url to which you are trying to redirect?